# Rails Couldn't find Student with id=search. Where is that coming from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, field

Ok, it's crunch time. I have a project I am working on and I can't get it to work. At the moment I need to create a search box, which is more like a simple text field that allows searching. The Problem is that whenever I hit the search button, I get the error "Couldn't find Student with id=search"

The thing I don't understand is: Why is ID getting assigned the value of "search"? I'm not understanding where in the code that this information is getting passed. There are only three files I have changed:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
def search
  @student = Student.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
  render :index
end
  # GET /students
  # GET /students.json

  def index
    @students = Student.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @students }
    end
  end

  # GET /students/1
  # GET /students/1.json
  def show
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @student }
    end
  end

  # GET /students/new
  # GET /students/new.json
  def new
    @student = Student.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @student }
    end
  end

  # GET /students/1/edit
  def edit
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /students
  # POST /students.json
  def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
        @student.courses << Course.find(1)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.save
        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @student, status: :created, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /students/1
  # PUT /students/1.json
  def update
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
          @student.courses << Course.find(params[:course][:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.update_attributes(params[:student])
        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /students/1
  # DELETE /students/1.json
  def destroy
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @student.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to students_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end

Assign3::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :courses

  resources :students

    resources :courses_students

  resources :students do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
end

<h1>Listing students</h1>


<%= form_tag(search_students_url, method: "get") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Student num</th>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>School</th>
    <th>Years attended</th>
    <th>Birthday</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @students.each do |student| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= student.student_num %></td>
    <td><%= student.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= student.last_name %></td>
    <td><%= student.school %></td>
    <td><%= student.years_attended %></td>
    <td><%= student.birthday %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', student %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_student_path(student) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', student, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Student', new_student_path %>
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated and many many thanks in advance.

Comment: I need your logs and probably routes.rb contents.

Comment: Need to see your search form and resources students block in router.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
Assign3::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :courses

  resources :students

    resources :courses_students

  resources :students do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end
end
```

With:

```
Assign3::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :courses

  resources :courses_students

  resources :students do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end
end
```

In routing the rule is first matched, first served, and you had 2 `resources :students`

Comment: Wow. I completely forgot about that. So I changed it but now I have a new error that I don't understand. 

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass 

Why does the each method work for displaying all the names in the database but not if I do a search?

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it. I messed up my SQL statement and my instance variable. Thank you so much for the help on this. =)